# Installing Oracle SOA Suite 12c using Java SE DK 10.0.01 on Windows 7

Tags: java, soa

at environment variables:

```
JAVA_HOME=E:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1
JDK_HOME=E:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1
JRE_HOME=E:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\jre
```

SET JAVA_HOME="E:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1"

However I cannot issue comand like:
E:>JAVA_HOME\bin\java.exe -version
error message= The system cannot find the path specified.

I check at C:\TEMP\orcl14937063252160533254.tmp\
there are DISK1 and DISK2 extracted.

My C:\TEMP\OraInstall2018-04-25_05-17-37PM\launcher2018-04-25_05-17-37PM.log is as folows:

```
2018-04-25 17:17:39,407 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Launcher log file is C:\TEMP\OraInstall2018-04-25_05-17-37PM\launcher2018-04-25_05-17-37PM.log.
2018-04-25 17:17:39,697 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Extracting to C:\TEMP\orcl14937063252160533254.tmp.
2018-04-25 17:17:39,855 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Extracting the installer . . .
2018-04-25 17:35:57,938 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Finished self extraction to C:\TEMP\orcl14937063252160533254.tmp.
2018-04-25 17:35:58,971 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.common.jni.WinRegistryHelper - Open  key failed: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432NODE\ORACLE
2018-04-25 17:35:58,973 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Using the parameter file: C:\TEMP\orcl14937063252160533254.tmp\Disk1\install\win64\oraparam.ini
2018-04-25 17:35:59,522 SEVERE [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Utils - This installer must be executed using a Java Development Kit (JDK)
but E:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.1 is not a valid JDK Java Home.
2018-04-25 17:35:59,696 SEVERE [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Launcher - This installer must be executed using a Java Development Kit (JDK)
but E:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.1 is not a valid JDK Java Home.
2018-04-25 17:35:59,698 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - The log is located here: C:\TEMP\OraInstall2018-04-25_05-17-37PM\launcher2018-04-25_05-17-37PM.log.
```

The error message is:
This installer must be executed using a Java Development Kit (JDK) but **E:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.1** is not a valid JDK Java Home.
The log is located here: C:\TEMP\OraInstall2018-04-25_05-17-37PM\launcher2018-04
-25_05-17-37PM.log.

Why it calling jre-10.0.1 instead of jdk-10.0.1?

Comment: What installer?

Comment: I am using command
e:>java -jar E:\Source\oracle\fmw_12.2.1.3.0_soaqs_Disk1_1of2\fmw_12.2.1.3.0_soa_quickstart.jar

JDK SE 10.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instrution at https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/SOAQS/integrated.htm#SOAQS206 should

```
edit from
SET JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_xx"
into
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1-10.0.1
```

without " (apostrophe symbol) and you must use your latest jdk version directory.

Then issue command at your extracted fmw_12.2.1.3.0_soa_quickstart.jar.
in my case i put *.jar at E:\Source\oracle\fmw_12.2.1.3.0_soaqs_Disk1_1of2

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -jar fmw_12.2.1.3.0_soa_quickstart.jar
```

Hope this information useful.

PS: i got help from geisterfurz00 at https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java

Answer (score 1):

Try running your command window as administrator:

[image]

Comment: yes, i do run cmd as administrator.
the solution is:

SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1-10.0.1
 then 
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -jar fmw_12.2.1.3.0_soa_quickstart.jar